# A task I don't understand

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Hi i have one task and I can't solve,the excercise is find div with class = "article" using classList property ,else return what that post is not found
here is a code of divs

```
 <div class="content" class="atricle">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum,<a href="#" class="link">link</a> dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Quas quidem doloribus dolor, qui doloremque deleniti
        alias. Iure, praesentium at? Esse non assumenda enim id in molestiae
        earum neque hic numquam!
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="content" class="news_post">
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum,<a href="#" class="link">link</a> dolor sit amet consectetur
        adipisicing elit. Quas quidem doloribus dolor, qui doloremque deleniti
        alias. Iure, praesentium at? Esse non assumenda enim id in molestiae
        earum neque hic numquam!
      </p>
    </div>
```

here is my solve

```
const allPosts = document.querySelectorAll("div")
function searchRes(allPosts){
if(allPosts.classList.toggle("article") = true){
  console.log(allPosts.article)
}else{
  console.log("There is no articles")
}
}
searchRes()
```

help me please :(

Comment: `=` is assignment. `===` is an equality check. Also, `toggle` _toggles_ that class name. it's not a getter.

Comment: Ae you sure you've understood the task? `document.querySelector("div.article")` will find the first div with the class `article`, no classList check needed.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to determine whether you are interested in exact or loose matches, that is, a `div` with a `class` being exactly equal to `article` is an exact match, while a `div` whose `class` is containing `article` is a loose match. This is why `c` is part of the second result, but not of the first, whereas `p` cannot be a result, because, even though it has a matching class, it's not a `div`. Note that the `articles` `class` is correctly ignored.

```js
let exactMatches = document.querySelectorAll("div[class=article]");

if (exactMatches.length) {
    let exactValues = [...exactMatches].map(item => item.innerHTML);
    console.log("Exact matches are: " + JSON.stringify(exactValues));
} else {
    console.log("No matches were found");
}

let looseMatches = [...document.querySelectorAll("div[class*=article]")].filter(item => item.classList.contains("article"));
if (looseMatches.length) {
    let looseValues = looseMatches.map(item => item.innerHTML);
    console.log("Loose matches are: " + JSON.stringify(looseValues));
} else {
    console.log("No matches were found");
}
```

```html
<div class="article">a</div>
<div class="article">b</div>
<div class="article something">c</div>
<p class="article">d</div>
<div class="articles something">e</div>
```

The `[...somevariable]` converts `somevariable` into an array, in our case, the result of `querySelectorAll` is an arraylike object (see more here https://www.capscode.in/blog/what-is-array-like-object-in-javascript) and as such, it des not have a `filter` method, so I converted it into an array in order to be able to neatly filter it.